# Codeigniter pagination does not display pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to make a pagination, but I have a problem with pagination can't create link

it is my controller

```
    public function getByDept($idDept = NULL, $offset = NULL) {    
      $config = array ( 'base_url'   => site_url('emp/emp/getByDept'),
                        'total_rows' => count($this->employee->get(array('idDept' => $idDept))),
                        'uri_segment'=> $this->uri->total_segments()
                      );
      $this->pagination->initialize($config);

      echo $this->uri->total_segments();

      $data['employee'] = $this->employee->get(array('idDept' => $idDept, 'limit' => 2, 'offset' => $offset));
      $data['pagings']  = $this->pagination->create_links();

      $this->load->view('emp/default', $data);
    }
```

and this my view

```
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($employee as $row) : ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 margin-bottom-60px">
              <div class="well well-sm">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <h4><?php echo $row["emp_name"];?></h4>                      

                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" onclick="view_master('<?php echo $row["id_aphris"] ?>')">Detail</button>
                  </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 col-md-8 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
              </div><!-- /.well well-sm -->
            </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 -->
            <?php endforeach ?>

    <div id="paging">
                    <?php 
                        echo $pagings; 
                        var_dump($pagings);
                    ?>
                </div><!-- /.pagination -->
        </div>
```

please can you tell me where is my problem code?

Answer (score 0):

post your view codes too.

what you get when you `var_dump($pagings);` on your view codes?

anyway I think it some problem on the $this->uri->total_segments();

Comment: I has used var_dump() but that's returned string 0, I've been edited my question and added some view.

Comment: This should be the comment and not answer.

Comment: set `'uri_segment' = 4` and check it again. (I mean pass it as hard code)
also check total rows that came to your controller